# MySqlCommand получить полный ответ в виде строки

Tags: c#, mysql

Необходимо из ответа на `SHOW CREATE TABLE <my_table_name>` - получить полный ответ сервера с  целью парсинга и нахождения Constraint для первичного ключа.
Т.е - например, в phpMyAdmin  - это выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в c# вытянуть весь ответ как одну строку?

```
 sql = "SHOW CREATE TABLE `" + TableName_textBox.Text + "`";
                command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 reader.Read();

                string s = ??????
```

Или есть другой способ, помимо парсинга ответа - получить внешний ключ и поле родительской таблицы, на которую он ссылается?

Comment: Я не спец по MySql, но эту информацию выдаёт PhpMyAdmin. Она не содержится в ответе запроса на создание таблицы. Её нужно получаить из системных таблиц. Например, так: https://stackoverflow.com/q/765176/5045688

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к знаю, что сообщество SO  - не одобряет ссылки в качестве ответа  -скопировал его сюда, но ниже - ссылка на оригинал:

```
  SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,   -- <<-- the one you want! 
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'My_Table';
```

Источник - ссылка на оригинальный и полный ответ:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102371/how-to-check-foreign-keys-related-to-a-table/102374#102374